# Bad video quality while using custom video source in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, agora.io

I try to use `SetExternalVideoSource`  and `PushVideoFrame` to send custom video frames to the RTC engine with methods described [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/custom_video_unity?platform=Unity). However, the video quality is not as good as using the default video streaming options despite that I am pushing video frames with the same resolution. Does anyone notice this difference before? I wonder if this is expected? Or maybe there is a way to set the custom video quality, but I overlooked?

[image: default video streaming]
[image: custom video]

Answer (score 0):

Hope [the slack channel answer](https://agoraiodev.slack.com/archives/CFDG7Q6F6/p1609284985284700) helped you on this.  For others reading this, please see what the discussion was:
"You should give a resolution configuration.  Here is the config I use in my advanced demo app:"

```
mRtcEngine.SetVideoEncoderConfiguration(new VideoEncoderConfiguration()
{
    bitrate = 1130,
    frameRate = FRAME_RATE.FRAME_RATE_FPS_15,
    dimensions = new VideoDimensions() { width = Screen.width, height = Screen.height },
    // Note if your remote user video surface to set to flip Horizontal, then we should flip it before sending
    mirrorMode = VIDEO_MIRROR_MODE_TYPE.VIDEO_MIRROR_MODE_ENABLED
});
```